# python match operator function based on condition

Tags: python, pypika

I'm a bit confused to uses multiple conditions while generating queries using pypika with the operator.

```py
from pypika import Field, Query

query = Query.from_('test').select('column1','column2')
query = query.where(operator.eq(Field('column1'), 12))
```

With the above code I can add condition with `operator.eq` for `equal` and we can have other operations as follows.

```py
operator.lt(a, b)
operator.le(a, b)
operator.eq(a, b)
operator.ne(a, b)
operator.ge(a, b)
operator.gt(a, b)
operator.not
```

In my case I get the operation value dynamically like

```
Equal
NotEqual
LessThan
LessThanOrEqual
GreaterThan
GreaterThanOrEqual
```

How can I form the query without adding lots of `if` conditions? instead, I am trying to find `operator.eq`, `operator.le(a, b)` with just `Equal`, `LessThanOrEqual` to a function and use them to `where` condition?

```py
query = query.where(operator.eq(Field('column1'), 12))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a python dict, like this:

```
import operator


operations = {
    'Equal': operator.eq,
    'NotEqual': operator.ne,
    'LessThan': operator.lt,
    'LessThanOrEqual': operator.le,
    'GreaterThan': operator.gt,
    'GreaterThanOrEqual': operator.ge,
}
```

and use it like this

```
query = query.where(operations[key](Field('column1'), 12))
```

where `key = 'LessThan' # Or NotEqual, Equal`

Comment: So simple and works! thanks!!! You killed my `if` conditions :D